# How to add @JsonIgnore annotated fields in serializing in Jackson ObectMapper

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I need to add `@JsonIgnore` annotated fields while serializing an object by `Jackson ObjectMapper`. I know you may offer me to remove the `@JsonIgnore` annotation from my class, but I need they are ignorable in some part of my application. And in another part of my application I need to have those `@JsonIgnore` annotated fields in my `json` string.

Comment: Maybe consider using a Jackson module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a SimpleBeanPropertyFilter and FilterProvider.

First annotate your class with custom filter like this:

```
@JsonFilter("firstFilter")
public class MyDtoWithFilter {

    private String name;

    private String anotherName;
    private SecondDtoWithFilter dtoWith;

    // get set ....
}
 @JsonFilter("secondFilter")
public class SecondDtoWithFilter{
    private long id;
    private String secondName;
}
```

and this is how you will dynamically serialise your object.

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // Field that not to be serialised. 
    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter firstFilter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("anotherName");
     SimpleBeanPropertyFilter secondFilter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("secondName");

    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("firstFilter", firstFilter).addFilter("secondFilter", secondFilter);

    MyDtoWithFilter dtoObject = new MyDtoWithFilter();
    String dtoAsString = mapper.writer(filters).writeValueAsString(dtoObject);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How can I add sub field in serializeAllExcept? I mean I have a class and one attribute of this class is another class. And this class also has some fields which should serialized or not

Comment: then in that case you must add the full path to your property.
updating answer code above for this. Happy Coding !! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. I still can see innerProperty2 inb my json string. but attribute1 is not in json as expected.

Comment: @gabby please edit my answer as well with your working code of nested properties. It will help others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing and re-adding them programmatically via reflection when your specific mapping is happening.

Answer (score 0):

That suggests to me you have two different models with some common elements.  I would reexamine your model.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainProgram {
    @JsonFilter("nameRemoveFilter")
    public static class User{

        private String name;

        private String age;

        private String password;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(String age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("nameRemoveFilter",
                SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("name","age"));
            // and then serialize using that filter provider:
            User user = new User();
            try {
                String json = mapper.writer(filters).writeValueAsString(user);
                System.out.println(json);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }


    Works for Latest version of Jackson after 2.0
```