# How to override @JsonInclude from controller in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

I have a POJO class which has the annotation `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` for the class.

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@Getter
@Setter
public class Attribute implements Serializable {
    private String type;
    private List<Object> value;
    private String unit;
    private List<Object> metaInfo;
}
```

and controller looks like this.

```
    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public Attribute getSingle() {
      return getAttribute(); // getAttribute() will get the object of type Attribute.
  }
```

Now, I have a requirement where based on the value of type field, need to return null for value field in the final JSON generated.

For example, if type='XYZ' the response will be `{ type:'XYZ'}`. And if type='ABC', then response should be `{ type:'ABC',value:null}`

How can I achieve this in Spring boot? Whats the best way to handle these kind of scenarios?

Comment: please refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672131/how-to-add-jsonignore-annotated-fields-in-serializing-in-jackson-obectmapper/35672470#35672470

Answer (score 0):

Can this help ?

```
if (value.getClass() == Integer) {
      return null;
}
```